# Wordpress show parents content on child page using custom loop

Tags: wordpress, loops, conditional-statements, parent-child

I created a hierarchical custom post type called "films." It is hierarchical so it can have children elements.

I am using a conditional statement in my single-films.php to show different content for the parent page from the children pages like so:

```
<?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php if( $post->post_parent != 0 ) {
    echo "Child Page";
} else {
    echo "Film Page";
} ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

In the condition that the page is a child, I want to use the values entered on the parents page, not the child page.  Because the loop has already been created, I need to figure out a way to pull content from the parent page JUST on the children pages. I need it to pull any content I wish (custom field, title, featured image, etc) from it's parent. Any idea how I can modify this loop to pull content from it's parent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wordpress has a nice [get_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post) function, you can use it like this to get the parent's title for example:

```
<?php 

if ($post->post_parent != 0) {
  $parent = get_post($post->post_parent); 
  echo $parent->post_title;
} ?>
```

You can access any custom field by its key/name and the parent's post id:

```
<?php

$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_meta($post->post_parent, 'custom-field-key', true));
echo '<img src="' . $image[0] . '" />';
?>
```

This works for sure with the [Advanced Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) Plugin for Wordpress.

Comment: what about custom fields, and shortcodes on its parent page? does it just work for title or can it work for any content on its parent?

Comment: can I use the above for grabbing any data I want from the parent element? I use advanced custom fields plugin to display custom fields from the parent with <?php get_field('image'); ?> and I want that to be available on the child page as well

Comment: wow, pretty cool! Can you also show how this would work for a typical custom field? Something like: <?php get_field('cast_members'); ?>

Comment: everything works great except for ACF's repeater field. The format is as follows:  <?php if(get_field('stream')): ?>

    <?php while(the_repeater_field('stream')): ?>
        <?php the_sub_field('stream_label'); ?> 
    <?php endwhile; ?>

 <?php endif; ?>

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not know how ACF handles those repeater fields inside the Wordpress database. As far as I know Wordpress offers flat key-value relations for custom fields or a list of values for a given key. But those "subfields" must be something new or somehow custom made by ACF.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit late but yeah it does work with the `ACF` but it only fetches you the thumbnail(cropped image). To get the the exact full image you will need to modify the code a bit.

```
<?php
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_meta($post->post_parent, 'custom-field-key', true), 'full');
echo '<img src="' . $image[0] . '" />';
?>
```

have fun.

Just thinking this might help someone in the future.